Opposite of "Compare Active File with Clipboard" in VSCode/VSCodium?
In other words, is there a way to swap the left/right inputs of the diff?
I want to see what changes pasting would bring to the current file.  E.g., if the clipboard has an extra line that the current file doesn't have, I want that to show as a green +, and not a red - like this feature currently shows.
